# change dropdown list items based on textbox value in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have an dropdown list which displays database column airport_names as items. Since the list is very very long, it becomes difficult for an user to scroll and select an item.

The database table contains airport_codes and airport_names. Now I want to place a textbox in which users can enter airport_code and resulting airport_name gets selected in dropdown list.

The list should contain selected item displayed as well as all other items if clicked.

I have an working code that displays item in dropdown list based on textbox code but I also want all other items in the list along with that. How to achieve both. Please help. Thank you in advance.

Here is my code:

```
public DataSet get_MST_SHIPPING_PORT_frm_Code(string code)
    {
        try
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Clear();
            string sql = "select PORT_NAME from MST_SHIPPING_PORT where PORT_CODE=@CODE";

            cmd.CommandText = sql;

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@CODE", SqlDbType.Char, 5).Value = code;

            OpenConnection();

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, con);
            da.SelectCommand = cmd;
            da.Fill(ds);
            return ds;
        }
}
```

On btn Click, following happens:

```
DataSet ds = _exportbll.get_MST_SHIPPING_PORT_frm_Code(code);
                if (ds != null)
                {
                    if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        ddlportto.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
                        ddlportto.DataTextField = "PORT_NAME";
                        ddlportto.DataValueField = "PORT_NAME";
                        ddlportto.DataBind();

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        lbl_msg.Text = "Invalid Code";
                    }
```

Comment: Can you include your code so we can get an idea of your application/process of loading these items?

Comment: Right now your code is doing what it intends to... Populate a dropdown based on code provided by user. Why do you want to retrieve *all* items irrespective of code provided?

Answer (score 0):

Although not recommended, but since you may have some business case, do the following:-

Have a **static** list of all ports, retrieved via

```
select PORT_NAME from MST_SHIPPING_PORT
```

Now on this list, implement autosuggest using various pluggins available (eg  [jQuery autocomplete](https://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/autocomplete/combobox.html), which will take in the value being typed and populate the dropdown with corresponding value.

With the values being retrieved as a static list, you will save on multiple trips to DB on each value entered, also this will be available for all users of your application.

The auto-complete will allow users to keep on typing the value and the result will get filtered automatically.

Comment: Thanks..I will try that.